# Why wordpress doesn't allow to add author filter to media library page in grid mode

Tags: filters, hooks, media-library, dropdown

It appears that W**ordpress doesn't allow to apply new author filter to upload page** (upload.php) in **"grid" mode**.

If it's right, why?

If not, does it exist a specific hook/function to allow that ?

The **"list" mode** reload the page and **"grid" mode** use ajax to filter.
Independently of that, can we load the upload.php page by default in list mode?

```
function media_add_author_dropdown(){
    $scr = get_current_screen();
    if ( $scr->base !== 'upload' ) return;
    global $mode;
    // Use of "mode" condition do nothing more but it well filter for list mode
    // if I use 'grid' === $mode it prevents the function from acting.
    if( 'list' === $mode || 'grid' === $mode) :
        $author   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'author', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $selected = (int)$author > 0 ? $author : '-1';
        $args = array(
             'show_option_none'   => 'Tous les utilisateurs',
             'name'               => 'author',
             'selected'           => $selected
        );
        wp_dropdown_users( $args );
    endif;
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'media_add_author_dropdown');
```